# API Correios GET TpObjeto where to find

Tags: get

I need a hand with the Correios API, respectively in GET, where can I find the categories of the 'tpObjeto' parameter? Example: If tpObjeto:01 is a box, tpObjeto:02 is ..., etc. etc. I read the documentation but couldn't find it.

Correios GET API

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem and after digging in multiple open source repositories, here is the options available for the parameter `tpObjeto`

- `1` - Envelope (default value);
- `2` - Box;
- `3` - Roll (rolo).

Already validated this values by matching the results with the expected prices.